# Xamarin forms android 9 crash

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-9.0-pie

I developed a Xamarin Forms app which works fine on Android 8. But I am getting crashes when I run it on Android 9.The crash seems to happen on transitioning from one page to another or when showing wait popups. Can anyone please help identifying the cause of these crashes which are only happening in Android 9. Below is the output in debug:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot set 'scaleX' to Float.NaN
android.view.View.sanitizeFloatPropertyValue()View.java:15549
android.view.View.sanitizeFloatPropertyValue()View.java:15523

android.view.View.setScaleX()View.java:14912
mono.android.animation.ValueAnimator_AnimatorUpdateListenerImplementor.n_onAnimationUpdate(Native Method)
mono.android.animation.ValueAnimator_AnimatorUpdateLis

tenerImplementor.onAnimationUpdate()ValueAnimator_AnimatorUpdateListenerImplementor.java:30
android.animation.ValueAnimator.animateValue()ValueAnimator.java:1547
android.animation.ValueAnimator.animateBasedOnTime()ValueAnimator.java:1339
android.animation.ValueAnimator.doAnimationFrame()ValueAnimator.java:1471
android.animation.AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame()AnimationHandler.java:146
android.animation.AnimationHandler.access$100()AnimationHandler.java:37
android.animation.AnimationHandler$1.doFrame()AnimationHandler.java:54
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run()Choreographer.java:1170
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks()Choreographer.java:984
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame()Choreographer.java:806
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run()Choreographer.java:1158
android.os.Handler.handleCallback()Handler.java:873
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage()Handler.java:99
android.os.Looper.loop()Looper.java:193
android.app.ActivityThread.main()ActivityThread.java:6863
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run()RuntimeInit.java:537
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main()ZygoteInit.java:858
Xamarin caused by: Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot set 'scaleX' to Float.NaN
Java.Interop.JniEnvironment.InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod(JniObjectReference instance, JniObjectReference type, JniMethodInfo method, JniArgumentValue* args)<8acc8089c2ed40d08469fbaa6710a44c>:0
Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod(string encodedMember, IJavaPeerable self, JniArgumentValue* parameters)<8acc8089c2ed40d08469fbaa6710a44c>:0
Android.Views.View.set_ScaleX(float value)Android.Views.View.cs:8908
Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementTracker.UpdateScale()
Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementTracker.HandlePropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementTracker.HandleRedrawNeeded(object sender, EventArg<T> e)
Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.BatchCommit()
Xamarin.Forms.AnimationExtensions.HandleTweenerUpdated(object o, EventArgs args)
Xamarin.Forms.Tweener.<Start>b__22_0(long step)
Xamarin.Forms.Internals.Ticker.SendSignals(int timestep)
Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AndroidTicker.OnValOnUpdate(object sender, ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateEventArgs e)
Android.Animation.ValueAnimator.IAnimatorUpdateListenerImplementor.OnAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation)Android.Animation.ValueAnimator.cs:147
Android.Animation.ValueAnimator.IAnimatorUpdateListenerInvoker.n_OnAnimationUpdate_Landroid_animation_ValueAnimator_(IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_animation)Android.Animation.ValueAnimator.cs:95
at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.19(intptr,intptr,intptr)
--- End of managed Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException stack trace ---
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot set 'scaleX' to Float.NaN
android.view.View.sanitizeFloatPropertyValue()View.java:15549
android.view.View.sanitizeFloatPropertyValue()View.java:15523
android.view.View.setScaleX()View.java:14912
mono.android.animation.ValueAnimator_AnimatorUpdateListenerImplementor.n_onAnimationUpdate(Native Method)
mono.android.animation.ValueAnimator_AnimatorUpdateListenerImplementor.onAnimationUpdate()ValueAnimator_AnimatorUpdateListenerImplementor.java:30
android.animation.ValueAnimator.animateValue()ValueAnimator.java:1547
android.animation.ValueAnimator.animateBasedOnTime()ValueAnimator.java:1339
android.animation.ValueAnimator.doAnimationFrame()ValueAnimator.java:1471
android.animation.AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame()AnimationHandler.java:146
android.animation.AnimationHandler.access$100()AnimationHandler.java:37
android.animation.AnimationHandler$1.doFrame()AnimationHandler.java:54
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run()Choreographer.java:1170
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks()Choreographer.java:984
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame()Choreographer.java:806
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run()Choreographer.java:1158
android.os.Handler.handleCallback()Handler.java:873
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage()Handler.java:99
android.os.Looper.loop()Looper.java:193
android.app.ActivityThread.main()ActivityThread.java:6863
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run()RuntimeInit.java:537
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main()ZygoteInit.java:858
```

Comment: add some code or we would just be speculating

Comment: What is your library that you used for transitioning? I find some similar cases, you could refer to them ;https://github.com/ronaldsmartin/Material-ViewPagerIndicator/issues/32 he changed another library:https://github.com/ongakuer/CircleIndicator  this issue was disappear. And this case https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager/issues/346

Comment: I have the exact same prob on Xamarin Forms and only on Android pie 9.0. A simple animation causes crash : `await view.ScaleTo(0.1, 0, Easing.CubicInOut);`

Comment: @deepak yadav. Do you use any external component that animates your page ? Like AnimationNavigationPage  from AlexandrNikulin ? We can find out whats going on, as I meet also the prob.

Comment: @Umar3x I am using Rg.Plugins. I had to comment the animation for it to work fine.

Comment: What do you mean exactly ? Was your animation played in a context of a PopUp page ? Ty

Comment: @Umar3x in your case, changing the code to `await view.ScaleTo(0.1, 10, Easing.CubicInOut);` (adding a very short delay) would solve the crash issue on android 9.0

Answer (score 0):

Someone might find this useful, I was getting this error while using `ScaleTo()` in Xamarin Forms. The code was working fine in **UWP**, but while running on Android (I tried on Android KitKat and Android Pie) I was getting this Error: `Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'Cannot set 'scaleX' to Float.NaN'`.

This error was because I was using `ScaleTo()` in `async` `Task`

**This was my code earlier**

```cs
void StartTimer()
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
       await TimerBar.ScaleTo(0, 5000, null);
    });
}
```

But this was giving me error as I was trying to modify UI elements on the thread other than the Main Thread. Please note that all the UI activities are carried on **Main Thread**. Changing or modifying UI elements or their properties does not work on other threads other than Main Thread. In Xamarin Forms if you are switching execution from Main Thread to another thread, use `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async() => awaited code...;)`. So I made changes in my code.

**This was modified code**

```cs
void StartTimer()
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
    {
        await TimerBar.ScaleTo(0, 5000, null));
    });
}
```

Also another way by directly calling on button click from XAML Page

```xml
<Button Text="Start Timer" Clicked="StartTimer" />
```

```
async void StartTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await TimerBar.ScaleTo(0, 5000, null);
}
```